# static library load of OpenCV causing app crash

Tags: java, android, opencv

The problem I am facing with is a failure in loading OpenCV Libs in my Activity class  like:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("openCVLibrary340");
    System.loadLibrary("stitcher");
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}
```

I have set up CMake and gradle so that now it is building the app but the app is crashing right from the start. If I try to remove the "openCVLibrary340" and "stitcher" the launches but crashes once there is a call to any `opencv` function or even when accessing the device's camera, the app just crashes, if I remove the `opencv` and try exactly  the same code, the camera works as it should.

Has anyone faced the same problem and solved? or is there anyone know the solutions to it? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You should also attach the error trace back.

Comment: System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3"); instead of  System.loadLibrary("openCVLibrary340");
try this